# FOUC in NextJS using Tailwind Css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, fouc

I have a FOUC on the production page of a site I'm working on using NextJS and TailwindCSS. It exists in varying degrees across browsers, but it seems to be worst on Desktop Firefox. You can view it here: [Bretton Does Nails](http://bretton-does-nails.vercel.app)

From what I've found I may be able to fix it by configuring a `_document.js` file, but I'm not sure how to set that up to work with Tailwind specifically.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to fix this or resources I can check out to figure out how to try the custom document?

Comment: From what I've found putting `<script>0</script>` on the start of the body section on `_document.js` might help to delay the first visible draw after the stylesheet is loaded, which is the root of the problem. 

However I think this has something to do with interoperability with postcss, Tailwind and NextJS.